# Older anime featuring girls in powered suits with limited battery life 'illegally' fighting mutated people

Tags: story-identification, anime

I can't remember too many specifics, but I think that they all had simplified suits of different colours and were mentored by a lady who was an ex-member, but had a white suit I think? They had occasional run-ins with authorities, likely were fighting these mutated people illegally. I remember at one point a guy was sort of brought in as like an intern/helper to them, with one distinct scene where he accidentally walks into their changing room and says something along the lines of 'I swear I didn't see anything, definitely didn't see your red underwear'.

Comment: This is a nice description, could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/58193) and see if there is anything else you could [edit] in? For example, you say it is an "older anime" do you know roughly how old is old?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like *Bubblegum Crisis*.

- The Knight Saber's hardsuits were primarily monochromatic - Priss in blue, Sylvie in white, Nene in pink, Lina in green.
- They had interactions with the police (it's the same world as another series, called *AD Police*). Nene was a police officer as her "dayjob", and there were important secondary characters on the force.
- The badguys were not mutants, but rather rogue machines called Boomers. The powerful ones did have a material-manipulation power that looked pretty freaky - swelling, bulging, tentacles, extra parts, stuff like that.
- Sylvie, the leader, owned a lingerie shop. They used the shops delivery van as a transporter for the hardsuits and their transforming motorcycles.
- The intern/helper was Mackie, Sylvie's younger brother. He walked in on them suiting up at least once.

Note that there are two versions of *Bubblegum Crisis*, an OVA from the late 80s, and *Bubblegum Crisis Tokyo 2040* a reboot released in the late 90s.

I'd have to rewatch them both, but if I recall correctly the hardsuits were explicitly battery powered in *BGC2040* and it was a plot point. I don't recall any particular emphasis on the power source in the original *BGC*, but its been a long time.

Furthermore, Sylvie's role was much more active in *BGC* than *BGC2040*, where she was more like a mentor and/or puppetmaster.

Of the two, it's more likely you're recalling the rebooted series rather than the original.

Comment: Thank you so much, this definitely looks like what I was looking for!!!